# Find current time between two fields in Oracle

Tags: oracle, date, odp.net, between

I have a situation where i need to raise an event everyday between 23:00 hrs to next day 01:00 hrs. 
My table has a data of date which will look like:

```
Start date          | EndDate
31-05-2016 23:00:00 | 01-06-2016 01:00:00
```

Already the database is designed like this and applications are live. Now, i tried getting the data using `BETWEEN` statement, but, nothing works how i need since the ENDDate is next day morning.

Could someone tell how to extract this data correctly.

My `ORACLE` Query

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) INTO P_OUTPUT FROM MAINTENANCE_LOG WHERE      
 NVL(RECCURING_TYPE,'O')='D' AND ACTIVE_STATUS='Y' AND
 TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'HH24MISS') BETWEEN TO_CHAR(START_DATE,'HH24MISS') AND TO_CHAR(END_DATE,'HH24MISS');
```

I tried converting this to date again, but it also does not work with the EndDate.

Update:
In my requirement I need only to check whether the current time is between the startdate or enddate time. I need to run this query everyday and it should do an activity between 23:00 and 1:00 of each day.

Note: If I run the query of `Sysdate between startdate and enddate` on 31-05-2015 i will get true/false. But, if I run this next day at night I will only get false since the EndDate is already over. So, I cant use the normal between date query.

Comment: Why are you to_charing a date field and using between?  Don't to_char them. Simply compare sysdate between start_date and end_date...  You're asking the engine to compare TEXT values. which should not be done ondates...

Comment: What's about `sysdate between start_date and end_date`?

Comment: Why i am doing a To_CHAR is even though my data is having a Date i only need to check the Current time is between 23:00 and 01:00. It should give me a count(*) based on it.

Comment: Please show more example rows of sample data, and expected output with details.  Edit the question, not in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
INTO   P_OUTPUT
FROM   MAINTENANCE_LOG
WHERE  RECCURING_TYPE = 'D'
AND    ACTIVE_STATUS  = 'Y'
AND    ( SYSDATE - TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN START_DATE - TRUNC( START_DATE )
                                      AND END_DATE   - TRUNC( START_DATE )
       OR
         SYSDATE - TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN START_DATE - TRUNC( END_DATE )
                                      AND END_DATE   - TRUNC( END_DATE )
       )
```

Answer (score 1):

If I get the question, you want to treat the times separately from dates. That is, 2016-MAY-31 23:00:00 should be treated as just 23:00:00 and 2016-JUN-01 01:00:00 should be treated as just 01:00:00 and treat these two times as a range? So if I was looking at a time of 23:47:43 or 00:23:11, both would be considered within the range but times like 22:56:34 and 01:34:52 would be outside of the range?

To go with a DATE datatype, your range spans two dates so you would need to put dates on the time input value such that a time like 00:23:11 would be looked at as YYYY-MM-DD 00:23:11 and make this date/time fall between your two date/times (START_DATE and END_DATE.)

In your example, 2016-JUN-01 00:23:11 would work but 2016-MAY-31 00:23:11 would not. Similarly for 23:47:23, 2016-MAY-31 23:47:23 would work but 2016-JUN-01 23:47:23 would not.

Basically, the rule could be as follows:
If the time you want to test has an hour < 12 (noon), append the date from the END_DATE, otherwise (hour >= 12) append the date from the START_DATE and compare the result with the date/times in START_DATE and END_DATE.

Perhaps something like this (I'm simulating your start/end dates table with a query here):

```
WITH test_data AS 
(SELECT '00:23:11' as time_char
   FROM dual
 UNION ALL
 SELECT '23:47:23' as time_char
   FROM dual
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT '22:56:34' as time_char
 FROM dual
 UNION ALL
 SELECT '01:34:52' as time_char
   FROM dual
 UNION ALL
 SELECT '12:34:52' as time_char
   FROM dual
 UNION ALL
 SELECT '23:00:00' as time_char
   FROM dual
 UNION ALL
 SELECT '01:00:00' as time_char
   FROM dual
 UNION ALL
 SELECT '22:59:59' as time_char
   FROM dual
 UNION ALL
 SELECT '01:0:01' as time_char
   FROM dual
)
SELECT test_data.time_char, start_end_table.*
FROM (SELECT TO_DATE('2016-MAY-31 23:00:00', 'YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI:SS') as start_date
           , TO_DATE('2016-JUN-01 01:00:00', 'YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI:SS') as end_date
        FROM dual
     ) start_end_table
     FULL OUTER JOIN
     test_data
     ON  
     CASE WHEN TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(test_data.time_char, 1, 2)) < 12 
           THEN TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(start_end_table.end_date, 'YYYYMMDD')||test_data.time_char, 'YYYYMMDDHH24:MI:SS')
           ELSE TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(start_end_table.start_date, 'YYYYMMDD')||test_data.time_char, 'YYYYMMDDHH24:MI:SS')
      END 
      BETWEEN start_end_table.start_date AND start_end_table.end_date
```

---

```
TIME_CHAR   START_DATE              END_DATE
00:23:11    2016-MAY-31 23:00:00    2016-JUN-01 01:00:00
23:47:23    2016-MAY-31 23:00:00    2016-JUN-01 01:00:00
23:00:00    2016-MAY-31 23:00:00    2016-JUN-01 01:00:00
01:00:00    2016-MAY-31 23:00:00    2016-JUN-01 01:00:00
01:34:52          (null)                   (null)
01:0:01           (null)                   (null)
22:59:59          (null)                   (null)
22:56:34          (null)                   (null)
12:34:52          (null)                   (null)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need convert date fields to char, only use dates and `BETWEEN` clausule to accomplish your select:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO P_OUTPUT 
FROM MAINTENANCE_LOG 
WHERE      
   NVL(RECCURING_TYPE,'O')='D' AND 
   ACTIVE_STATUS='Y' AND
   SYSDATE BETWEEN START_DATE AND END_DATE;
```

Anyway, in your question... you could add `YYYYMMDD`... but please, don't do it if you are using date fields.

```
TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,   'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') BETWEEN 
TO_CHAR(START_DATE,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') AND 
TO_CHAR(END_DATE,  'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')
```

Comment: I have done those. But, my requirement is to only extract the time and compare the current time against the Start and End time. Let us say today when i am running the query it will return true since it is 31st of May. But tomorrow when i run the End date is already over.

Answer (score 0):

This is work for me :

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
INTO   P_OUTPUT
FROM   MAINTENANCE_LOG
WHERE  RECCURING_TYPE = 'D'
AND    ACTIVE_STATUS  = 'Y'
AND  SYSDATE BETWEEN YEAR_FROM and YEAR_TO
```